# How to trigger click on keypress with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, keypress, keyup

I need to trigger click on some keypress action, also if it's a up or down key on my keybord script will be removing some class from specify element. So keypress is working but trigger and up down press not, this is my code, ths for help.

```
$('.main_search_field').keypress(function(evt){
    $('.live_search_plugin').addClass('visible');

    var scroll_pane = $('.scroll-pane');
        scroll_pane.click();
        scroll_pane.trigger('click');
    if (evt.keyCode == 40) {
        $('.live_search_list ul li').removeClass('active');    
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to trigger the click? It's better to assign a handler to the click event and then just run the handler wherever you need.

Comment: bc i heve the list in scroll-pane and if i click on it i can scroll this list by keys up and down, before click i'm scrolling the whole page - body

Comment: I see! in that case you need to put focus on this list (but only visible inputs, links and buttons can be focused). triggering a click will not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 50;
$(".main_search_field").trigger(e);
```

In `e.which` put code for required character.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the evt keypress like so:

```
if (evt.which == 40) {  }
```

When using keypress, usually I check for which key I want to interact with before running any code inside my function. If you don't do this, your code will run with any keypress.

Answer (score 0):

`.keypress()` might not be your best solution here, you could be better off using `keydown()` and `keyup()`, or to use the full version: `.bind('keydown', handler)` (ditto for keyup)

From the jquery docs:

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.
>   http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

`.click()` is shorthand for `.trigger("click")` and you are using it fine, but do you actually have a click handler on `$('.scroll-pane)`?

Your code will (assuming browser dependencies) cause two clicks to be triggerred on `$('.scroll-pane')` and then the `if()` to be evaluated. But you haven't shown us your click handler for `scroll-pane` so we can't see if that's at fault.

Comment: my scroll pane block is a live search, so when i'm typing some words on my search input the scroll pane block is showing, in the same time i want to trigger click at this list/scroll_pane for scrolling this list by keyup keydown